# ! LaTeX3 Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected. (LaTeX3) Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted! (LaTeX3)

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I can't compile my R Markdown files with *knitr*. The error message I get is the following:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
(LaTeX3)        Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
(LaTeX3)        
(LaTeX3)        The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX3)        is dated 2021-07-12, but in your TeX tree the files require
(LaTeX3)        at least 2021-08-27.
```

I think the problem might be related to my last R update, via `updateR()` from the package *installr*, even though I've already tried to reupdate it.

Answers to previous related questions like [Mismatched LaTeX support files detected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576918/mismatched-latex-support-files-detected) didn't work for me.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.8.7)  6 SEP 2021 12:03
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**R6---EA.tex
(./R6---EA.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-07-12> (c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count182
\c@section=\count183
\c@subsection=\count184
\c@subsubsection=\count185
\c@paragraph=\count186
\c@subparagraph=\count187
\c@figure=\count188
\c@table=\count189
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.s
ty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.
sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.st
y
Package: amsmath 2021/04/20 v2.17j AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.st
y
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen139
))
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen140
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count190
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count191
\leftroot@=\count192
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count193
\DOTSCASE@=\count194
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box50
\strutbox@=\box51
\big@size=\dimen141
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count195
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count196
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count197
\dspbrk@lvl=\count198
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count199
\column@=\count266
\maxfields@=\count267
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen142
\alignsep@=\dimen143
\tagshift@=\dimen144
\tagwidth@=\dimen145
\totwidth@=\dimen146
\lineht@=\dimen147
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.st
y
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.s
ty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
) (c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+lmr on input line 11
2.
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)) (c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.s
ty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks22
\inpenc@posthook=\toks23
) (c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.st
y
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
) (c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.st
y
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color
.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdfte
x.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.
sty
Package: hyperref 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hypertext links for LaTeX

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.
sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdfte
xcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwar
err.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.st
y
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks24
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetk
eys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvd
efinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfesc
ape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.st
y
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltx
macro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.st
y
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoption
s.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen148
\Hy@linkcounter=\count268
\Hy@pagecounter=\count269

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.de
f
File: pd1enc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-
langpatches.def
File: hyperref-langpatches.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: patches for babel la
nguages
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.
sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmd
s.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count270

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 4073.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4192.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4197.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4200.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4207.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4212.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4445.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count271
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4804.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen149

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.st
y
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigin
tcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count272
\Field@Width=\dimen150
\Fld@charsize=\dimen151
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6076.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6081.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6084.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6091.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6096.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6101.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6106.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6146.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6150.

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.
sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count273
\c@Item=\count274
\c@Hfootnote=\count275
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.d
ef
File: hpdftex.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx
.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery packag
e
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count276
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count277

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rer
unfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/un
iquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip52
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.
sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\Gm@cnth=\count278
\Gm@cntv=\count279
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count280
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen152
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen153
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen154
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen155
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen156
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen157
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen158
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen159
\Gm@dimlist=\toks25
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.
sty
Package: fancyvrb 2021/08/12 v3.8 verbatim text (tvz,hv)
\FV@CodeLineNo=\count281
\FV@InFile=\read2
\FV@TabBox=\box52
\c@FancyVerbLine=\count282
\FV@StepNumber=\count283
\FV@OutFile=\write3
) (c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.st
y
Package: framed 2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
\OuterFrameSep=\skip53
\fb@frw=\dimen160
\fb@frh=\dimen161
\FrameRule=\dimen162
\FrameSep=\dimen163
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.
sty
Package: graphicx 2020/12/05 v1.2c Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.
sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graph
ics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen164
\Gin@req@width=\dimen165
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/grffile/grffile.st
y
Package: grffile 2019/11/11 v2.1 Extended file name support for graphics (legac
y)
Package grffile Info: This package is an empty stub for compatibility on input 
line 40.
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/indentfirst.
sty
Package: indentfirst 1995/11/23 v1.03 Indent first paragraph (DPC)
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.
sty
Package: biblatex 2020/12/31 v3.16 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.
sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count284
) (c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.st
y
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count285
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
)) (c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count286
\c@listtotal=\count287
\c@listcount=\count288
\c@liststart=\count289
\c@liststop=\count290
\c@citecount=\count291
\c@citetotal=\count292
\c@multicitecount=\count293
\c@multicitetotal=\count294
\c@instcount=\count295
\c@maxnames=\count296
\c@minnames=\count297
\c@maxitems=\count298
\c@minitems=\count299
\c@citecounter=\count300
\c@maxcitecounter=\count301
\c@savedcitecounter=\count302
\c@uniquelist=\count303
\c@uniquename=\count304
\c@refsection=\count305
\c@refsegment=\count306
\c@maxextratitle=\count307
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count308
\c@maxextraname=\count309
\c@maxextradate=\count310
\c@maxextraalpha=\count311
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count312
\c@highnamepenalty=\count313
\c@lownamepenalty=\count314
\c@maxparens=\count315
\c@parenlevel=\count316
\blx@tempcnta=\count317
\blx@tempcntb=\count318
\blx@tempcntc=\count319
\blx@maxsection=\count320
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count321
\blx@notetype=\count322
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count323
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count324
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count325
\blx@entrysetcounter=\count326
\blx@biblioinstance=\count327
\labelnumberwidth=\skip54
\labelalphawidth=\skip55
\biblabelsep=\skip56
\bibitemsep=\skip57
\bibnamesep=\skip58
\bibinitsep=\skip59
\bibparsep=\skip60
\bibhang=\skip61
\blx@bcfin=\read3
\blx@bcfout=\write4
\blx@langwohyphens=\language4
\c@mincomprange=\count328
\c@maxcomprange=\count329
\c@mincompwidth=\count330
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.de
f
File: blx-dm.def 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count331
\c@savedafterword=\count332
\c@annotator=\count333
\c@savedannotator=\count334
\c@author=\count335
\c@savedauthor=\count336
\c@bookauthor=\count337
\c@savedbookauthor=\count338
\c@commentator=\count339
\c@savedcommentator=\count340
\c@editor=\count341
\c@savededitor=\count342
\c@editora=\count343
\c@savededitora=\count344
\c@editorb=\count345
\c@savededitorb=\count346
\c@editorc=\count347
\c@savededitorc=\count348
\c@foreword=\count349
\c@savedforeword=\count350
\c@holder=\count351
\c@savedholder=\count352
\c@introduction=\count353
\c@savedintroduction=\count354
\c@namea=\count355
\c@savednamea=\count356
\c@nameb=\count357
\c@savednameb=\count358
\c@namec=\count359
\c@savednamec=\count360
\c@translator=\count361
\c@savedtranslator=\count362
\c@shortauthor=\count363
\c@savedshortauthor=\count364
\c@shorteditor=\count365
\c@savedshorteditor=\count366
\c@labelname=\count367
\c@savedlabelname=\count368
\c@institution=\count369
\c@savedinstitution=\count370
\c@lista=\count371
\c@savedlista=\count372
\c@listb=\count373
\c@savedlistb=\count374
\c@listc=\count375
\c@savedlistc=\count376
\c@listd=\count377
\c@savedlistd=\count378
\c@liste=\count379
\c@savedliste=\count380
\c@listf=\count381
\c@savedlistf=\count382
\c@location=\count383
\c@savedlocation=\count384
\c@organization=\count385
\c@savedorganization=\count386
\c@origlocation=\count387
\c@savedoriglocation=\count388
\c@origpublisher=\count389
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count390
\c@publisher=\count391
\c@savedpublisher=\count392
\c@language=\count393
\c@savedlanguage=\count394
\c@origlanguage=\count395
\c@savedoriglanguage=\count396
\c@pageref=\count397
\c@savedpageref=\count398
\shorthandwidth=\skip62
\shortjournalwidth=\skip63
\shortserieswidth=\skip64
\shorttitlewidth=\skip65
\shortauthorwidth=\skip66
\shorteditorwidth=\skip67
\locallabelnumberwidth=\skip68
\locallabelalphawidth=\skip69
\localshorthandwidth=\skip70
\localshortjournalwidth=\skip71
\localshortserieswidth=\skip72
\localshorttitlewidth=\skip73
\localshortauthorwidth=\skip74
\localshorteditorwidth=\skip75
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compa
t.def
File: blx-compat.def 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.
def
File: biblatex.def 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
\c@textcitecount=\count399
\c@textcitetotal=\count400
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count401
\c@biburlbigbreakpenalty=\count402
\c@biburlbreakpenalty=\count403
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count404
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count405
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count406
\biburlbigskip=\muskip18
\biburlnumskip=\muskip19
\biburlucskip=\muskip20
\biburllcskip=\muskip21
\c@smartand=\count407
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.bbx' found.

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numer
ic.bbx
File: numeric.bbx 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/stand
ard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count408
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count409
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.cbx' found.

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numer
ic.cbx
File: numeric.cbx 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex citation style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\supercite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.
cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
))
\@quotelevel=\count410
\@quotereset=\count411

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backen
d-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-08-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count412
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box53
) (./R6---EA.aux)
\openout1 = `R6---EA.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 106.

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epsto
pdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstop
df-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 106.

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.s
ty
Package: nameref 2021-04-02 v2.47 Cross-referencing by name of section

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.
sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/g
ettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count413
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 106.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 106.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 106.
(./R6---EA.out) (./R6---EA.out)
\@outlinefile=\write5
\openout5 = `R6---EA.out'.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(71.13188pt, 472.03123pt, 71.13188pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(56.9055pt, 666.9326pt, 71.13188pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=472.03123pt
* \textheight=666.9326pt
* \oddsidemargin=-1.1381pt
* \evensidemargin=-1.1381pt
* \topmargin=-52.36449pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/engli
sh.lbx
File: english.lbx 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
Package biblatex Info: Document encoding is UTF8 ....

(c:/Users/VITOR/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-08-27 L3 programming layer (loader)
```

Comment: Can you show the complete .log file?

Comment: I'm sorry, but where can I get my .log file?

Comment: it should be in the same folder than your rmd file, maybe you need `keep_tex: true` in your header, idk

Comment: Great, and now edit your question and show the complete .log file so we have code formatting

Comment: The file is too long. So I'm gonna paste the end of the file in the following comments. I'm so sorry for the inconvenient.

Comment: ! LaTeX3 Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
(LaTeX3)        Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
(LaTeX3)        
(LaTeX3)        The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX3)        is dated 2021-07-12, but in your TeX tree the files require
(LaTeX3)        at least 2021-08-27.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.77      \ExplLoaderFileDate{expl3.sty}}
                                         %

Comment: Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 17283 strings out of 480482
 288322 string characters out of 5897121
 802875 words of memory out of 5000000
 34793 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 406420 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 16 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 60i,1n,66p,740b,759s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: I guess either `tinytex::tlmgr_update()` or `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The error message you have shown indicates that there is a mismatch between the version of expl3.sty package compared to the version of the L3 programming layer in your LaTeX installation.
To be more specific, the LaTeX format version you have is dated 2021-07-12, but the expl3.sty file in your TeX distribution requires at least 2021-08-27. This issue is common due to mismatched versions. To resolve this issue you can update your TeX distribution (assuming tinytex) using `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()`.

It is recommended to update your TeX distribution before you re-install it. For this, you can use `tinytex::tlmgr_update()` command.

Keep Coding!

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr
try running `fmtutil-sys --all` (which you may need to do as root/sudo/whatever the Windows equivalent is) and/or `fmtutil-user --all`

Somewhere there's mismatched files, which you should be able to find with `kpsewhich --engine=pdftex --all pdflatex.fmt` (or possibly `kpsewhich --engine=pdftex --all pdflatex-dev.fmt`).
Rebuilding the format with the above commands (for system or user installations, respectively) should fix your problems.
I had a slightly more convoluted case where my distribution package manager placed one in a subfolder of my home directory and one in the `/usr/local` tree from a direct TexLive install - in my case I simply deleted the older file to reflect the current distribution I was using.

Sources:
https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/811
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576918/mismatched-latex-support-files-detected